# How to get an implicit instance like TypeTag does in a method?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, macros

I am struggling with a problem and I can't realise how to solve it. I hope more experienced Scala programmers can shed me a light!

I have the following macro:

```
object Model { 

        trait Model[T <: Product] {
           def showAttrs(): Unit 
         } 

        def getModel[T <: Product]: Model[T] = macro getModelImpl
 }
```

The purpose of the macro is to return a Model instance that shows the T's attributes (if T is a case class)!

I want to be able to do the following:

```
def f[T <: Product](implicit m: Model[T]): Unit = { 
       m.showAttrs() 
 } 

 case class Number(n: Int) 

 f[Number]()
```

The principle is the same as scala reflection when we do the following:

```scala
case class Number(n: Int)
def getInfo[T](implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = println(tag)
```

See?! We get an instance of Type :) (GREAT!).

How to do such thing? Does the scala reflection package provide some concrete implicit behind the scenes? If so, how can I accomplish the same result?

Comment: Try to change your `getModel` to `implicit def` and import it in target source

Comment: @Odomontois Great! It worked like a charm! Thank so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What  should your `MyTypeTag[T]`  accomplish?

If your trait is invariant on `T` and has not any type-dependent logic at all, simplest solution could be define method

```
implicit def arbMyTypeTag[T] = new MyTypeTag { ... }
```

More complex variant depends on other resolved implicits

```
implicit def optionMonoid[T: Semigroup] = new Monoid[Option[T]] { ... }
```

Even more complex variant depends on same type

```
implicit def tupleMonoid[A,B](implicit ma: Monoid[A], mb: Monoid[B]) = new Monoid[(A,B)]{...}
```

Compiler is able to resolve such recursive implicits.

The most hardcore approach is to use whole compile-time information on type and expression via [implicit macro](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html) which is the closest to things like `TypeTag` resolution, which could lead to [very complex bugs](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9048)

Comment: I changed the question! Please check it!